# When reloading UITableView make it so it doesn't scrolls to thew top

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios

I have an UITableView populated with a Twitter timeline. I also have scroll to refresh (like Tweetie/Twitter) and when user scrolls to refresh, new content is added to the top. How would I do so the table view adds the content to the top of the actual position. In other way, I don't want to have the latest tweet the first at reload, instead new content should be added to the top of the actual position, having to scroll to the top to see latest tweets. Hope you guys have understood it as it could be a bit difficult to understand ;)

Comment: Just to make sure I'm understanding correctly, you want to refresh the page making the current view the new origin for the tableView?  In other words, you want to have the tableView show you the newest updates when you refresh, but without having to scroll the whole way to the top?

Comment: So instead of adding content to the top, you want to add it where the user is right now?

Comment: To answer the question from headline: Use insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:

Comment: what I want is, if the user is at the top, when he/she reloads by pulling to refresh, content is added to the top, but the table doesn't moves, it stands where the latest tweet was before refreshing, having to scroll up for checking new tweets :)

Comment: You could have taken a peek into UITableView class reference and you'd find – scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:
– scrollToNearestSelectedRowAtScrollPosition:animated:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @TheBlack, that helped me :)

Quote >

```
You could have taken a peek into UITableView class reference and you'd find – 
scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated: – 
scrollToNearestSelectedRowAtScrollPosition:animated
```